# NoMethodError when trying to highlight header in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a Rails beginner and I'm working on movie database app and having some trouble getting this header to highlight when I click it.

The following is in my views directory, using haml.

```
%table#movies
  %thead
    %tr
      %th{ :class => hilite('title')}= link_to "Movie Title", movies_path(:sort => 'title'), :id => "title_header"
      %th Rating
      %th{ :class => hilite('release_date')}= link_to "Release Date", movies_path(:sort => 'release_date'), :id => "release_date_header"
      %th More Info
```

Then I have the following in my application.css file.

```
table#movies hilite {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

I get the following error when I run it on localhost server through cloud9.

```
NoMethodError in Movies#index
undefined method `hilite' for #<#<Class:0x00000003500fe8>:0x007f1afc229520>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very acquainted with HAML, but looking at some sample usage in the tutorial site, I think I may know what the issue is. 
Currently, you have this:

`%th{ :class => hilite('title')}= link_to "Movie Title", movies_path(:sort => 'title'), :id => "title_header"`

However, `hilite` is not a method. It is just a class name that you want to use in your CSS file, so you should change it for this:

`%th{ :class => "hilite" }= link_to "Movie Title", movies_path(:sort => 'title'), :id => "title_header"`

Also, to save you a bit of trouble, I noticed you missed a `.` in your CSS:

```
table#movies .hilite {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Let me know if this was what you were looking for. Cheers!

Comment: I replaced the line and added the period, but now it's just highlighted by default, when it needs to be highlighted when I click it.

Comment: Well, generally you would use Javascript to take care of the sorting and highlighting instead of doing a full page refresh. But I see what you're trying to do. In this case, you need an if/else or ternary operation that checks the sort parameter. Something like `:class => sort == 'title' ? "hilite" : "" `. You should probably also abstract this to a helper method so you don't have logic in your markup.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that last sentence please?